# Accessing object values that have reserved keywords as names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I'm accessing the Amazon AWS API using the ruby-aaws gem, but without going to much into details of the API or the gem, I think my problem is more of a general nature.

When I query the API I will end up with "object array", let's call it `item`, containing the API response.
I can easily access the data in the array, e.g. `puts item.item_attributes.artist.to_s`

Now the API returns attributes whose identifier are reserved words in Rails, e.g. **format** or **binding**.

So doing this:
`puts item.item_attributes.format.to_s` will return *method not found*

while
`puts item.item_attributes.binding.to_s` will return some object hash like `#<Binding:0xb70478e4>`.

I can see that there are values under that name when doing
`puts item.item_attributes.to_yaml`

Snippet from the resulting yaml show *artist* and *binding*:
`--- !seq:Amazon::AWS::AWSArray

- !ruby/object:Amazon::AWS::AWSObject::ItemAttributes

  __val__:

  artist: !seq:Amazon::AWS::AWSArray

    - !ruby/object:Amazon::AWS::AWSObject::Artist

      __val__: Summerbirds in the Cellar

  binding: !seq:Amazon::AWS::AWSArray

    - !ruby/object:Amazon::AWS::AWSObject::Binding

      __val__: Vinyl`

This was probably a very detailed explanation with a very simple solution, but I can't seem to find the solution.

**edit**
Finally found it. I guess it is because it is an array of objects, duh...
`puts item.item_attributes[0].binding.to_s`

Comment: What does `item.binding` return?

Comment: `Object#binding` returns the scope of that object. That's ruby, not rails.

Comment: item.binding returns nil.The problem is that I cannot use item.item_attributes.binding as syntax because 'binding' is a reserved word. While a word like 'artist' isn't, therefore item.item_attributes.artist works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. I guess it is because it is an array of objects, duh...
`puts item.item_attributes[0].binding.to_s`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to access the individual attributes by using `[]` instead of the method name (which is probably provided using `method_missing` anyway).

So, `item.item_attributes[:artist].to_s` may return what you want. If it doesn't it would be worth trying `'artist'` as the key instead.

Comment: Doesn't work error message is: `[]': Symbol as array index (TypeError)

Comment: Ah, looks like item['artist'] may do what you want. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: No avail: `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)